# What happens when slip direction is the same as applied force?

Tags: material-science, crystals, fracture

Using the equation

$$ \tau R = \sigma y \cos \left( \phi \right) \cos \left( λ \right) \tag{1} $$

means that when the angle $\phi$ between the tensile axis and slip plane normal is $90$, $\cos \left( 90 \right) = 0$ so the resolved sheer stress $\tau R$ is $0$. Is this due to fracture? Why is it $0$ conceptually?
[image]

Comment: Why would tensile stress aligned with the slip axis result in slip? There is no reason for two adjacent planes to slip relative to each other.